# "something which" or "something that"

Tags: relative-pronouns, that-vs-which

According to Korean English grammar books, nouns that ends with "thing", such as something, anything, generally take "that" as a relative pronoun.

But does that mean that "something which" is not preferred? If so, are there any rules?

> It is not just the newness of contemporary literature that makes it different, but also the context in which it is written and received, **something which** gives it a very interesting edge over the literature of the past. ([excerpt](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=WUUSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=It+is+not+just+the+newness+of+contemporary+literature+that+makes+it+different,+but+also+the+context+which+it+is+written+and+received,+something+which+gives+it+a+very+interesting+edge+over+the+literature+of+the+past.&source=bl&ots=z_WOoOafqT&sig=zGAS4x1PGNfNybua6p5EV560tPk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOz5WhypnTAhUHl5QKHeBFD5EQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=It%20is%20not%20just%20the%20newness%20of%20contemporary%20literature%20that%20makes%20it%20different%2C%20but%20also%20the%20context%20which%20it%20is%20written%20and%20received%2C%20something%20which%20gives%20it%20a%20very%20interesting%20edge%20over%20the%20literature%20of%20the%20past.&f=false))

In the sentence, "something which" is used because "which" can be used as non-restrictive, but "that" cannot be used so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is traditionally accepted to use **that** for a restrictive clause and **which** for a non-restrictive clause.

> In modern English usage, “that” always introduces a restrictive clause
>   (due to which it is almost never set off by commas).

- The box that lies on the table is empty. *(correct)*

> In British English, it is absolutely fine to use “which” in
>   restrictive as well as non-restrictive clauses.

- The box which lies on the table is empty. *(correct in British English)*

This sentence above is usually perceived as incorrect in formal American English.

**Extra information:**

> There are several issues with this rule. First of all, it is a
>   prescriptive rule, and most Americans don’t strictly follow it in
>   speech (many being unaware of its existence altogether). Secondly,
>   when “which” is combined with a preposition, noun, or a pronoun, it
>   cannot be replaced by “that”, even when it introduces a restrictive
>   clause (this is considered to be an exception to the rule), as in:

- The principle **in which** he believes has been proved wrong. *(correct)*
- The principle **in that** he believes has been proved wrong. *(incorrect)*

Comment: Please, explain the downvotes

Comment: I've voted the explanation UP as it seems adequate to me and I can't see any reason or explanation for the downvotes. I should add that the great majority of non-American English speakers wouldn't know the rule either. (I have lived on 4 continents!)

Comment: Apparently I downvoted you - sorry. *You last voted on this answer 5 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.* I was unaware of these distinctions between BrE and AmE, and I find the info educational. I will gladly un-downvote this when able.

Answer (score -1):

"which" refers to the state of being (e.g. characteristics, specifications) of an indicated noun, almost as if one would afterwards want to add some comments (e.g. adjectives) to the noun for a broader view or perspective.

If this is not the intention and the context needs no further explanation, then the use of "that" is common rule.

Remark: when a preposition needs to be used to refer to the noun, always combine with "which".